Run pghero with a port other than 8080
I want to deploy pghero as a sidecar to my spring boot application inside a k8s cluster.
As my spring application already occupies 8080 port of the pod, I would like to configure pghero to use a different port. Is this possible ?
Went through the documentation but couldnt find anything besides this really old issue:
https://github.com/ankane/pghero/issues/86
Tried the mentioned sudo pghero config:set PORT=3030 commands but apparently this is not working like this anymore.

Just creating a custom Dockerfile like this:
FROM ankane/pghero
ENV PORT=3000
EXPOSE 3000/tcp

